# $x \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{r=1}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{xr}{n}}{1+\frac{x²r²}{n²}}\right)$ into an integral.

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

$$x \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{r=1}\frac{1}{n}\ln\left(\frac{1+\frac{xr}{n}}{1+\frac{x²r²}{n²}}\right)$$ into an integral.

So this beast right here is the result of a bigger one: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^n(x+n)(x+\frac{x}{2})\dots (x+\frac{n}{n})}{n!(x²+n²)(x²+\frac{n²}{4})\dots (x²+\frac{n²}{n²})}\right)^{\frac{x}{n}}$$ but that's another thing, no need to check on that since I know for a fact that it is correct and it does arrive to the thing above. All I have left os to transform that riemanm sum into a definite integral, but the issue is that I'm unsure on how to do so. Any hints or tips? I've noticed that $dx=\frac{1}{n}$, since it's outside of the function $\ln$ but that's the most I have been able to get to.

Comment: Your expression, before the limit is the Riemann sum with uniform partition for the integral $\int^x_0\ln\Big(\tfrac{1+t}{1+t^2}\Big)\,dt$

Comment: how? no explanation for it? can you please explain how you got that? and why is there an x in the upper bound, that makes no sense, it should be a definite integral

Comment: My comment is intended to be taken as a hint. Consider the interval $[0,x]$ ($x$ is fixed) and divide it into $n$ pieces of the same size $x/n$. Notice that $x\sum^n_{k=1}\frac1n\log\Big(\frac{1+\tfrac{kx}{n}}{1+\tfrac{k^2x^2}{n^2}}\Big)$ can be written in the form
$$ \sum^n_{k=1}f(t^*_k)h$$
where $h=\tfrac{x}{n}$, $t^*_k=0 + \frac{(x-0)}{n}k$, and $f(t)=\log\Big(\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}\Big)$

Comment: still very confused, I've understood that $dt=\frac{1}{n}$ or $h$ or whatever you want to call it, and I also understand that the integral ends up being $\int_0^x\ln(\frac{1+t}{1+t^2})dt$. But let me update with a new question since my doubt now comes from a video I saw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***An overview***

- For simplicity, suppose $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a nice continuous function.
- Divide the interval in $n$ pieces, not necessarily of the same length. That is, consider points $\mathcal{P}=\{a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b\}$.
- For each subinterval $I_k=[t_{k-1},t_k]$, ($k=1,\ldots,n$), choose a point $t^*_k\in I_k$. Call this $t^*_k$'s *tags*,  and denote the set of tags as $\tau_{\mathcal{P}}$.
- The Riemann sum for the partition $\mathcal{P}$ and tans $\tau_{\mathcal{P}}$ is defined as
  $$S(f,\mathcal{P},\tau_{\mathcal{P}})=\sum^n_{k=1}f(t^*_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$$
- As you may have seen from your Calculus course, as the partition $\mathcal{P}$ gets finer and finer, and no matter what tags $\tau_{\mathcal{P}}$ one chooses the Riemann sums converge to a number, denoted as $\int^b_a f$ (or $\int^b_b f(t)\,dt$).
- Equivalently, (all this takes substantial effort to make it rigorous terms but let's not worry about that here) as the size of the partition $\|\mathcal{P}\|=\max_{1\leq k\leq n}(x_k-x_{k-1})$ gets smaller and smaller, no matter what tags $\tau_{\mathcal{P}}$ one chooses, the Riemann sums converge to a number, denoted as $\int^b_a f$ (or $\int^b_b f(t)\,dt$).

So far I am probably not telling anything new, but let's use this as a simple overview.

As you may know already, all continuous functions on $[a,b]$ are Riemann integrable, that is the *limit* of the Riemann sums exists. In particular, we may consider uniform partitions of $[a,b]$, that is partitions of the form $t_k=a+\frac{b-a}{n}k$, $k=0,\ldots, n$, in which case $x_k-x_{k-1}=\frac{b-a}{n}=h_n$. Since the choice of tags is not important, we may as well choose the endpoints (right for example) of the subintervals $I_k=\big[a+h_n(k-1),a+h_nk]$, $k=1,\ldots,n$. Then
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum^n_{k=1}f\big(a+k\tfrac{b-a}{n}\big)\frac{b-a}{n} =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} h_n\sum^n_{k=1}f(a+kh_n)=\int^b_a f$$

***Back to you original problem:***
The sum in your problem can be written as
$$
S_n=x\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{1}{n}\ln\Big(\frac{1+\tfrac{xk}{n}}{1+\big(\tfrac{xk}{n}\big)^2}\Big)=\frac{x}{h}\sum^n_{k=1}\ln\Big(\frac{1+\tfrac{x}{n}k}{1+\big(\tfrac{x}{n}k\big)^2}\Big)=
h_n\sum^n_{k=1}\ln\Big(\frac{1+h_nk}{1+\big(h_nk\big)^2}\Big)
$$
where $h_n=\frac{x}{n}$. This corresponds to a Riemann sum with uniform partition over $[0,x]$ with $n$ subintervals of size $h_n$ and using the right-end points of subintervals as tags, and function $f(t)=\ln\Big(\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}\Big)$. Hence
$$S_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^x_0\ln\Big(\frac{1+t}{1+t^2}\Big)\,dt$$

I hope this clarify matters.

Comment: I'm sorry this is over my level of math, the only thing on my level is the very last part, and I'm still having issues understanding. Still appreciate your effort though, ty

Comment: Okay confirming, I've understood your last part and hence how to do it,.thanks. I would appreciate if you'd look over my last question related to this